# How to play file from external storage in exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

From assets all working fine!
But from external storage no.

This is my exoplayer instance:

```
// ExoPlayer
        val renderesFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(
            this,
            DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF
        )
        val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector()
        exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            this@PlayerService,
            renderesFactory,
            trackSelector
        )
        exoPlayer!!.addListener(exoPlayerListener)
```

Here I'm trying to build a path:

```
val dirPath = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(audio.uri)!!.absolutePath
val filePath = "$dirPath/001.mp3"
val audioFile = File(filePath)
val uri = Uri.fromFile(audioFile)
prepareToPlay(uri)
```

audio.uri --> "Downloads/audio_reading/"
And this is prepareToPlay() method:

```
private fun prepareToPlay(uri: Uri) {
            if (uri != currentUri) {
                currentUri = uri
                val userAgent = Util.getUserAgent(this@PlayerService, "ExoPlayer")
                val mediaSource = ExtractorMediaSource(
                    uri,
                    DefaultDataSourceFactory(this@PlayerService, userAgent),
                    DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null
                )
                exoPlayer!!.prepare(mediaSource)
            }
        }
```

When I start app and click "play" I'm getting that error:

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.music.app/files/Downloads/audio_reading/001.mp3: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:73)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:250)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:886)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.music.app/files/Downloads/audio_reading/001.mp3: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:485)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:288)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:151)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:65)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:250) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:886) 
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:381) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:475)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: It seems like the file you want to play is a directory. Try deleting it and run the code again.

Comment: But file must be there and it's not a directory. It's the mp3 file

Comment: Do you have the permission for reading external files?

Comment: yes. I'm asking for permission when app starts

Comment: Hmm ok, could you try to delete the download folder and rerun the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the error is indicting that the system is seeing the path you are trying to open not as a file but as a directory.

> open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)

You code to open the file looks good so one common reason for an error like this is that the code that actually created or stored the file created a directory rather than a file - e.g. if the following is called:

> yourFilePath.mkdirs()

This will actually create a directory called 'yourFilePath' rather than create a directory for a file called 'yourFilePath'.

Comment: Yea, you right. Thanks a lot!
the problem was that I tried to work with the SD card, but the system worked outside the SD card. And inside the SD-card was my file, but inside the Android/data/file/... was a folder.